Transitive join to an entity referenced by several other entities
I have the data schema depicted in the image below
TPCH schema
I have constructed cubes describing this model.
Here is an example of a description of one of the cubes.
cubes:
  - name: tpch_lineitem
    sql: >
      select * from tpch_lineitem

    joins:
     - name: tpch_orders
       relationship: many_to_one
       sql: "{tpch_lineitem}.L_ORDERKEY = {tpch_orders.O_ORDERKEY}"

     - name: tpch_partsupp
       relationship: many_to_one
       sql: >
          {tpch_lineitem}.L_PARTKEY = {tpch_partsupp.PS_PARTKEY} and
          {tpch_lineitem}.L_SUPPKEY = {tpch_partsupp.PS_SUPPKEY}

    dimensions:
      - name: L_ORDERKEY
        sql: L_ORDERKEY
        type: number
        primary_key: true
        public: true
      
      - name: L_PARTKEY
        sql: L_PARTKEY
        type: number
        primary_key: true
        public: true
      
      - name: L_SUPPKEY
        sql: L_SUPPKEY
        type: number
        primary_key: true
        public: true
    ...

Using the existing semantic layer I want to build a view in which I plan to output information about the supplier's country and the customer's country.
views:
   - name: view_tpch
     public: true
   
     cubes:
         - join_path: tpch_lineitem
           includes:
              - COUNT_L_SUPPKEY
              - COUNT_L_PARTKEY

         - join_path: tpch_supplier
           includes: 
               - S_SUPPKEY
               - S_NAME

         - join_path: tpch_customer
           includes: 
               - C_CUSTKEY
               - C_NAME

        - join_path: tpch_customer.tpch_nation
           includes:
              - name: N_NATIONKEY
                alias: cust_N_NATIONKEY
              - name: N_NAME
                alias: cust_N_NAME

         - join_path: tpch_supplier.tpch_nation
           includes:
              - name: N_NATIONKEY
                alias: supp_N_NATIONKEY
              - name: N_NAME
                alias: supp_N_NAME

However, I encountered a problem that when outputting the Nation entity - the connection is only along the chain: lineitem -> orders -> customer -> nation.
That is, no matter how I try to output the supplier's country and the customer's country at the same time, I always see the result for the customer's country. In fact, the path to nation is absolutely always built through customer (I guess it's logical for Dijkstra's algorithm), but it doesn't fulfill my expected function :(
How can I correctly compose the cube model to solve the problem described above?
Please note that after nation I also want to output the description of entity region for both “branches” ( customer and supplier).
I don't know if this is an important clarification, but I plan to interact with cube.js exclusively via the SQL API
Thanks in advance for the help!
I tried many different options, and the only one I found that worked was to “extend” an existing Nation cube with two child cubes, tpch_suppliers_nation and tpch_customers_nation.
However, I don't think this is a good solution, because this way we lose the benefits of the semantic layer, and create a hardcoded chain of relationships, which affects further relationships (similar problems will occur with further cubes, e.g. region will similarly have to be prescribed further - and all other entities will be multiplied by the number of such problematic entities as customer and supplier).
